# How to display specific div content using php for every specific day of a week?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html, dayofweek

I am working on a php project in which I want to show data in following way using PHP.

So when its `'X'` day, PHP will display contents of a certain div element along with its CSS effects.

Example here are the variables/info:

```
Title : What to Eat ?

Monday - eggs, bread, turkey <br/>
Tuesday - oats, rye, wheat bread<br/>
Wednesday - Milk , chicken, fish<br/>
```

Note: I want to keep the time as per `Indian standard time [IST]`

So when the day is `Monday`,

It will display below:

```
What to Eat ?<br/>
eggs, bread, turkey 

[this will be the content of monday and css will be used for styling it in div]
```

When its tuseday it will display:

```
What to Eat ?<br/>
oats, rye, wheat bread
```

When its Wednesday it will display:

```
What to Eat ?<br/>
Milk , chicken, fish
```

---

How do i achieve the above please help me,  what php code to use for it or is then a more easy way to it.
I want to make such thing  for a whole week display `[Mon -Sunday]`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use array in this operation. Consider this as an example:

```
<?php

$food = array(
    'Monday' => 'Eggs, Bread, Turkey',
    'Tueday' => 'Oats, Rye, Wheat Bread',
    'Wednesday' => 'Milk, Ckicken, Fish',
    'Thursday' => 'Eggs, Bread, Turkey',
    'Friday' => 'Oats, Rye, Wheat Bread',
    'Saturday' => 'Milk, Ckicken, Fish',
);

// use date function, then you can use this as a 'key' on the array
$day_today = date('l');

?>

<!-- HTML -->

<p>What do eat</p>
<p><?php echo $food[$day_today]; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using PHP [DATE()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $day = date("l");
    if( $day == "Monday" ){
        echo "<div>Some content for monday</div>";
    } else if($day == "Tuesday" ){
        echo "<div>Some content for Tuesday</div>";
    } else if($day == "Wednesday" ){
        echo "<div>Some content for Wednesday</div>";
    }
?>
```